# How to Show certificate if user pass the quiz in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to issue a certificate if user pass a quiz in drupal. i had did that but certificate is shown automatically. i want to hide that certificate until user has passed the quiz. how can i do that by defining costume action in rules.

Answer (score 0):

Check the form id of your quiz panel and hide the visibility of the certificate until quiz is over. Once the quiz is done, turn on the visibility of the certificate using css.

OR

If your page acts as a node, then you can perform the operation by using `hook_node_submit`.